# How has the snipping tool for Windows 11 become mapped to the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+S when using Rider?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, shortcuts

I use [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) both at work and at home. At work I can access the Rider settings using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. At home though, when I use this keyboard shortcut the snipping tool opens thus inteferring with accessing the Rider settings.

I discovered that you can also access the snipping tool via the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> from [this article](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/open-snipping-tool/) which seems to be the usual shortcut.

I've tried searching through all the directories on my machine to see if there's a shortcut which links to the underlying executable for the snipping tool which maybe have accidentally been configured with this keyboard shortcut but I've had no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Evernote ?

Comment: @harrymc yes I am

Comment: Does it happen when Evernote is not running ? Evernote uses Ctrl+Alt+S to capture the screen into a new note.

Comment: @harrymc I killed the Evernote application and it stopped happening. Thanks for spotting this. Wasn't aware of the Evernote shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Evernote is running, it uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to capture the
screen into a new note.

You need to stop Evernote to avoid this problem.